# How ro replace d3.rainbow

Tags: d3.js

With `d3.v4.0.0-alpha.35.min.js` used in [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/b07f8ae91c5e9e45719c), there is a `rainbowColor()` function which is now missing in `d3.v4.min.js`:

```
var color = rainbowColor()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
```

Would anyone know if this function was moved or renamed or if a working version of that example exists using other color schemes? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `d3v4` and `d3v5`, you can use:

```
var color = d3.scaleSequential()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  .interpolator(d3.interpolateRainbow);
```

instead of:

```
var color = d3.scaleRainbow()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
```

which translates for your example into:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    size = Math.max(width, height);

var color = d3.scaleSequential()
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI])
  .interpolator(d3.interpolateRainbow);

var circles = d3.packSiblings(d3.range(2000)
  .map(d3.randomUniform(8, 26))
  .map(function(r) { return {r: r}; }))
  .filter(function(d) { return -500 < d.x && d.x < 500 && -500 < d.y && d.y < 500; });

svg
  .select("g")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.angle = Math.atan2(d.y, d.x)); })
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return Math.cos(d.angle) * (size / Math.SQRT2 + 30); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return Math.sin(d.angle) * (size / Math.SQRT2 + 30); })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r - 0.25; })
  .transition()
  .ease(d3.easeCubicOut)
  .delay(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y) * 10; })
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

circle {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="960" height="960"><g transform="translate(480,480)"></g></svg>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

where `scaleSequential` is part of the [d3-scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) sub-module and `interpolateRainbow` is part of the [d3-scale-chromatic](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale-chromatic/blob/master/README.md#interpolateRainbow) sub-module.

There have been major api changes between d3 versions 3 and 4. `d3.v4.0.0-alpha.35.min.js` was probably an early alpha version of the version 4 still using the version 3 api for that particular function.

Comment: the domain of `scaleSequential` is [0..2pi]. But `atan2()` gives a result of [-pi..pi]. How is the [-pi..0] part mapped on the range?

Comment: As I understand it, [scaleSequential](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleSequential) is a continuous scale (in this case for a domain [0, 2pi]) which would mean -pi/2 (out of the domain) would be mapped to 3pi/2 (within the domain) via a modulo of the domain length. Thus `color(-0.5 * Math.PI) = color(1.5 * Math.PI) = rgb(255, 94, 99)`. Using [0,2pi] instead of [-pi,pi] would then have for consequence to give a pi offset to the scale and thus a rotation of the rainbow by 180°.

Comment: the docs speak about extrapolation for out of domain values (if clamp is false) but I can't find the modulo explanation, maybe a feature of the interpolator. But the interpolator gets a value between [0..1] and that is determined by the `domain` part of the scale. Undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1):

In d3v6 this has changed to

```
var color = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateRainbow)
  .domain([0, 2 * Math.PI]);
```